# Adding the contents of a folder but not the folder itself to github?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to get my github pages to work by uploading the contents of my _site/ folder (generated by jekyll) to my repo. Unfortunately, when I'm inside _side/ and use the following command:

```
git add .
```

It adds the directory and the files contained inside it, instead of just the contents of the directory. (IIRC, for github pages to work, the contents of the website cannot be nestled inside a directory).

I've tried removing the folder and adding each file manually, but somehow github still adds the whole _site/ folder. Any thoughts?

Comment: that's not possible.. where would the files go if they aren't in that folder?

Comment: Is there any way to make the _site/ directory the 'base' directory of the repo then?

Comment: you probably want to look into how to create a gh-pages branch like this: https://gist.github.com/chrisjacob/825950

Comment: What folder contains this `__site` folder? Are there other files in the parent folder which need to be tracked by version control?

Answer (score 3):

Technically, git does not add the folder. For example, you cannot add an empty folder and commit it. Instead, git tracks the location of each file which is committed to the repo. This means that it is impossible to commit a file and remove the information about which folder contains it. You have two options to get almost what you want:

1. Move the files to a different folder.
2. Create a git repo in the folder where they are currently located. If the parent directory also contains a git repo, then you will need to use the submodules feature of git.